# Doctrine extend Parser

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to extend the Doctrine Parser: `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser`. In detail I want to add a `ComparisonOperator` that I need for a custom Query.

Is this possible without changing the File?

Answer (score 0):

[In general it is not possible to extend the Parser](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/7ILei7WvmMc)

But it is possible to create a workaround to add the @> functionality.

```
class JsonbContains extends FunctionNode
{
    public $identifier = null;
    public $value = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->identifier = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_NONE);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_GREATER_THAN);
        $this->value = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return '(' .
        $this->identifier->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ' @> ' .
        $this->value->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        ')';
    }
}

SELECT p
FROM AppBundle:Project p
WHERE JSONB_CONTAINS( p.values @> '{\"ACTIVE\": \"1\"}' ) = TRUE
```